# I want to pass the some fields such as purchase name and vender in purchase order in to Bills I mean create Automatic new record

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

this is my code but when I executed the function it doesn't work

the below code that I executed but doesn't work with me I want some one to help me I'm using odoo16

```
def button_landed_cost(self):
        # Assuming you have the necessary data (purchase name, vendor, etc.)
     
        purchase_name = self.name
        vendor_id = self.partner_id.id
        # Create an entry in the account.move model
        account_move = self.env['account.move'].create({
                'partner_id': vendor_id,
                'ref': purchase_name,
            # Add other relevant fields...
        })

        if account_move:
            print(f"Account move created successfully with ID: {account_move.id}")
        else:
            print("Failed to create account move")

        return True
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work".  Does it give you an error?  What happens?  What do you want it to do?

Comment: the code not work i want to do when I running the function must create two fields purchase name in bill reference and vender in vender in bills form

Comment: Please explain in detail what it is you want the code to do.  What happens when you run that code.  "the code not work" is not helpful.  Better yet, please include a minimal reproducible example.  As written right now, no one can help you since there's no way to replicate your problem.

Comment: let me explain you I want to do function name it  button_landed_cost in purchase.order class the function I will define in xml button so when I running the function must create new vender bills like Create Bills but create in vender bill two filed purchase name in bill reference and  vender in vender  but the function   is not helpful

Comment: Please explain in your original post and not in the comments.  pardon me for being utterly dense, but I don't understand your comment.  What do you mean by create new vender bills?  Where is it created?  What is ```self.env['account_move']```?

Comment: I think you don't understand me no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should create an accounting move which you can see under accounting entries if you remove filters.

To create a bill, you need to set the move type to `Vendor Bill`

***Example:***

```py
account_move = self.env['account.move'].create({
    'partner_id': vendor_id,
    'ref': purchase_name,
    'move_type': 'in_invoice',
    # Add other relevant fields...
})
```